# Producing list of available reports to drop into spreadsheet

Tags: reports

I'm new to CiviCRM so this may be a naïve question but is it possible to extract a list of reports that I can drop into a spreadsheet for circulation? Idea is to send a list out for review (what do we need, what can we get rid of?.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Hi Mike - welcome. by 'what can we get rid of', are you talking CiviReports?

Comment: Hi Pete, over the years a number of reports have been produced that I think may no longer be required. I want to send a list of them as a spreadsheet so people can comment and we can declutter the screen to make useful reports more accessible.

Comment: Your best bet is likely to be to access mysql and take the data direct from civicrm_report_instance